# Laravel Retrieving Specific fields from nested Relationships

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have some nested relationships,
Following are my models:
Post, Thread and BookPage.
and their relationships:

**Post**

```php
class Post extends Model
{

    public function thread(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Thread');
    }

}
```

**Thread**

```php
class Thread extends Model
{

    public function bookPage(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\BookPage');
    }

    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

}
```

**BookPage**

```php
class BookPage extends Model
{

    public function threads(){
        return $this->hasMany(App\Threads);
    }

}
```

now i wanted to get posts with the bookpages and threads but only some fields let say only thread name and bookpage title

I have read about retrieving relationships and i am doing exactly like explained in the docs but here is my problem :

When i am retrieving posts with relations without specifying fields i am getting results fine:

**Query:**

```php
$posts = Post::with('thread.bookpage:id,title)->get();
return $posts->toArray();
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

but when i specify fields for both i.e fields for bookpage and also fields for thread i am getting bookpage as null.
I am able to get specific fields for one relation only either for bookpage or either for thread.
I have tried to query in the following ways:

```php
$posts = Post::with('thread.bookpage:id, ...')->get();
//thread:all fields, bookpage:specified fields

$posts = Post::with('thread.bookpage', 'thread:id, ...')->get();
//thread:specified fields, bookpage:bull
```

Here is the result if i tried to specify fields for both:
[image]

so how can i get the specific fields only from the relation and its nested relation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to select all the foreign keys (here: `thread.book_page_id`) that Laravel requires to match the eager loading results to their parents:

```php
$posts = Post::with('thread:id,book_page_id', 'thread.bookpage:id,title')->get();
```